# Can't find cartridge chamber in Canon Pixma MG25775

Tags: printer, canon-pixma, cartridge

[image]

I have this Canon Pixma MG25775 printer. Lately, it was printing blurred copies so I bought a new cartridge.

I looked up on youtube where the cartridge chamber was, and I opened up that chamber. But my chamber is just empty as you can see in my image. There's supposed to be two black boxes there where I'm supposed to insert it.

Despite this, the printer is still printing somewhat blurred copies, so I think it has a cartridge somewhere. Can someone please help?

Comment: Is the printer powered on? The printhead should move to the centre when you open the covers.

Comment: See this link: https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/W/MG2500%20series/EN/BG/bg-ink1000.html

Comment: And, you may need to run a Print Head Alignment, from the same link.

Comment: @hdhondt thanks. i was able to insert the cartridge now, but it's still printing blurry pages (except for a few, which it prints fine for some reason). What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This isn't a forum: https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

To replace the cartridge, the printer needs to be powered on. Then, opening the front cover will cause the printer to position the head in the middle, ready for cartridge replacement.

The blurring may also be cause by a head misalignment, which can be fixed by running a Print Head Alignment.

Both of the above are documented in the [user manual](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/W/MG2500%20series/EN/BG/bg-ink1000.html):

Finally, the "blurring" could be caused by blocked jets, which can be fixed by [cleaning the jets.](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/W/MG2500%20series/EN/BG/bg-maintenance1400.html) However, it would be useful to see a sample of a blurred page.